# Show exposed pager as links instead of select box

Tags: 7, views, paging

How to show exposed pager as links instead of select box in drupal 7 views ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help, Use [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)
go to settings of better exposed filter 
[image]

[image]